# Generate all Combinations of resource distribution

Tags: math, generator, combinatorics, enumeration, enumerate

I have *m* "slots" with indivual capacity *c_m*. Now I want to distribute a certain amount of integer *k* to those *m* slots without exceeding their capacity *c_m*. Such that every slot has a certain "contingent" between 0 and *c_m* and the sum of all contingents equals *k*.

Now I want to generate all the combinations, without duplicates and in a most efficient way. Obviously I don't need to differntiate between coningents of same value. The slots have an identity though, so that their order matters.

I hope that describes my problem understandable (no homework btw).

My guess is that the best way would be to generate one trivial solution and then generate the next combination out of the previous one. I would then restrict the difference between the new and the previous combination to at most 2, for subtracting 1 at one slot and adding 1 to another slot. From that I only need a way to identify duplicates when I'm about to generate one. But I'm open for other ideas, too.

Comment: It is worth to explain what are duplicates, because your slots have distinct capacity and seem distinguishable

Comment: yes the slots have an identity. Duplicates are all m-tuples that have the same contingent in the same order as an already generated instance.

Comment: so assume for a minute we would save each instance as an integer-list. Then every list with the same integer value at the same index as any other instance would be a duplicate. I'm in search of a more efficient way than naive comparison, because that would be too time consuming.